# can i use a map i created with arcmap for arcgis runtime sdk for android?

Tags: android, eclipse, arcgis, arcgis-server

i am trying to use arcgis run time sdk for android to do a navigation app for my final project.and i am new to arcgis at all,so i followed all the rules and installed the arcgis plugin to my eclipse and tried to run the samples.but all the samples i found fetch the map from arcgis.com,but since my connection was slow, i was wondering if anyone can tell me how to use some sample maps i created using arc-map in my project.i have arcgis 10.0 installed and use eclipse luna.please help me cause i cant go any further with out this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches you can take:

- Add a raster using the [FileRasterSource class](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/raster/FileRasterSource.html).
- Add vector data using [GeodatabaseFeatureTable](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/geodatabase/GeodatabaseFeatureTable.html), [GeopackageFeatureTable](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/geodatabase/GeopackageFeatureTable.html), or [ShapefileFeatureTable](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/geodatabase/ShapefileFeatureTable.html).
- If you can upgrade ArcGIS Desktop to 10.1 or higher, you can [create a tile package](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00660000045m000000).
- If you can upgrade ArcGIS Desktop to 10.2 or higher, you can [create Runtime content](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00660000045q000000).

Comment: okay i managed to obtain arcgis desktop 10.1 and created a tile package.so can u tell me on how to use what i created for my android app.a link to any clue would be very appreciated.

Comment: Follow the "[add a map to your app](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/add-a-map-to-your-app.htm)" tutorial, and then in your onCreate method, create an [ArcGISLocalTiledLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/ags/ArcGISLocalTiledLayer.html) and add it to your MapView.